# Unable to understand a stty option for Emacs in OS/X

Tags: emacs

[Steve](http://stevey-home.blogspot.com/2008/04/osx-for-emacs-users.html) recommends to run the following code before you start your Emacs

```
stty erase ^\?
```

I get after running it

```
stty: illegal option -- Backups
usage: stty [-a|-e|-g] [-f file] [options]
```

**Steve's blog post**

> Note that the ^\? - - dorks the Delete key by making it send
>   a ^H, but enables the C-h sequence in
>   Emacs. Note that C-Delete does a
>   normal backward-delete-char, so just
>   remember that when you're backspacing
>   in a terminal, hold the control key
>   down.

**How can you see what Steve's command does?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command works fine for me.  At first I thought perhaps you weren't using bash, and the ^ or \ characters were being interpreted differently, so I tried csh and sh and it still worked fine.  Are you sure that you're typing "^" (shift 6) "\" (not /) and "?" (normal question mark)?

You can try it like this:

```
stty erase "^?"
```

which should have the same effect.

If that doesn't work, I can't help since I don't have access to OS X.  Good luck!

Comment: I use Zsh. Your command seems to work with quotes. However, I am still unsure where to see the difference: Should I see the difference in Emacs or outside of Emacs? -- I run the command, type "nonsense" and pressed a backspace => a letter was removed.

Comment: See my other answer for outside emacs.  Within emacs, if I remember correctly, the default binding for ^h was help, and the DEL key was bound to backup-and-delete.  This stty command makes DEL do backup-and-delete, so it's consistent.  The defaults may have changed, or your settings may be different.  I know that the backspace key has worked "right" for me both within and outside emacs for a few years, without me having to do anything special.  What problem are you having, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Randy: Thank you! I now know what the command does - it solved a problem for me at my server.

Answer (score 1):

*How can you see what Steve's command does?*

If the command is successful, there will be no output.  However, it's easy to see what it has done: at the prompt type something then try to backspace over it.  Instead of erasing what you typed, you'll get ^H displayed for every backspace you type.

To return things to normal, use this command:

```
stty erase ^h
```

(that's just shift 6, then h)

As with my first answer, this works for me on Ubuntu with bash.  However, it may be different on OS X.